# Entity Framework Connectionstring

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am using entities with VisualStudio 2010. When I debug my ASP.NET application, it is using the current user identity to connect to the database, and not what is specified in my connection string :

> ```
>    <connectionStrings>
>      <add name="RFV2_Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.RFDB.csdl|res://*/Model.RFDB.ssdl|res://*/Model.RFDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider
>  connection string=&quot;data source=xxx\xxx;initial
>  catalog=xxx;User Id=xxx;Password=yyy;integrated
>  security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
>  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />    </connectionStrings>
> ```

Do I have to specify something to make my application use the connection string identity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify either "Integrated Security=True" OR "User Id" and "Password", not both.

See [this list of keywords](http://connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords), which specifies for "Password":

> The password for the SQL Server account logging on. **Not used with** (the strongly recommended) **'Integrated Security=true' option**.

(my emphasis)